# SEM path coefficients - what do they mean?

Tags: r, self-study, interpretation, structural-equation-modeling, regression-coefficients

so my model in SEM has an good fit, and I let R plot my model including path co-efficients (it is automated so I figure the numbers on all paths are path coefficients?).

I cant get a grip on what they mean though... can anyone shed a light on it?
Is there a cut-off value like with RSMEA?
When are they significant?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

A parameter estimate in a structural equation model is either a covariance (curved arrow) or a regression parameter (straight arrow). They are interpreted in the same way as you interpret these parameters in any more. It's a little easier to explain if you gave an example.

Comment: I measure the influence of three Latent variables (A,B,C) on one Mediator (D) and one final outcome (E). All are straight arrows and I have to write a page of interpretation on what the values of the arrows mean. All arrows from A have negative numbers ranging from -0.001 to -0,23. B has 0,67 to D but 1,9 to E. C has 0.7 to both D and E. The straight error between D and E has a value of 0.09.

Comment: Straight error?

Comment: So this is homework? Please tag with self-study.

Comment: *straight arrow + edited the tag. Am new to the forum so pardon me please.

Comment: Do you have a path diagram you can post? It's easier to explain if you do.